# Is Express.js not supposed to have Autocomplete in VSC?

Tags: javascript, express

So before all, I searched the whole internet with "Express.js intellisense" "Express extension VScode" "Express Autocomplete"...etc

And I found nothing so my question is, is there anyway to get Autocomplete/intellisense for Express?

It seems like 0 options show up when I write anything related to it. Is it normal or not?

Comment: Auto completion in javascript is due to its weak type system in general very limited.

Comment: If you're using typescript you can use @types/express - Visual Code will autocomplete for you.

Comment: @Bergur I'm using Javascript. Is it still going to work?

Comment: @Bergur I did it and it works. Thank you a lot! The post can be closed now. I got my answer.